# Android : Why does startNativeTracing() not work on REAL devices?

Tags: qemu, android-testing, android

I have an Android app with most of the code written in native. I want to use `startNativeTracing()` to get the trace files for the native code. But I find that the function works only for emulator (QEMU) and not on the actual real device.

Why is the function not usable on the real device?

Is there any other way to get the trace files while the app is running on the actual device?

Comment: I would like to know more about this also.